# React Native - iOS - Too big app when hermes is enabled

Tags: ios, react-native

When I create a `react-native` app with `hermes` enabled, .app size is +500 mb and even installed on device is still +500 mb. I though that I might have done something wrong so i started new blank project (`0.70.2`) and nope, it still weights the same. I inspected .app file and most of the size comes from hermes. Is there a way to decrease the size? Will this be solved by itself when uploading to app store?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same problem with react-native v 0.70.2

Comment: Same. Could you find a solution?

Comment: No, just bear with it :( .